# Conditional missing arguments in R function?

Tags: r, magrittr

I'm trying to work with a function in R that allows for only one of two arguments to be passed, through a series of `missing(arg)` calls. I cannot easily modify the function.  My data is such that sometimes I supply one argument and other times the other.  Is it possible to have some variant of:

```
myFunction(arg1 = switch(condition == T, arg1, NULL), 
           arg2 = switch(condition == F, arg2, NULL))
```

When I run the function like that, it counts the switch function as an argument and not a NULL object.  Wrapping each `switch` in `eval` doesn't help either.

Thanks for the help!

Post script: I know this is bad practice, and I should have the call the function specified by the condition.  But this is part of a `magrittr`-style pipeline that I'd rather not disturb.

Comment: Have you tried using `ifelse`? E.g. `arg1 = ifelse(condition, arg1, NULL)`.

Comment: Two notes, not directly related to the question: (1) use `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead of `T` and `F`. The latter are *variables* that can be redefined. Use the constants. (2) Don’t use logical literals in comparisons and tests, this is not useful. Instead, just write `condition` or `! condition`. Or, if (and only if!) `condition` is not necessarily a logical vector of length 1, use `isTRUE(condition)`.

Comment: @Frédéric it appears to pass the entire statement as the argument, unfortunately.  But this is fine, obviously not the "real" solution anyway

Answer (score 2):

You're probably much better off using @user2554330 's solution, or, as it seems from comments that you're fine with considering NULL and missing to be equivalent, use `missing(arg1) || is.null(arg1)` in your code.

Nevertheless If we really want to type `myFunction` once only and keep it as is we could do the following :

```r
myFunction <- function(arg1, arg2) {
  if(missing(arg2)) 
    paste(arg1, "apples")
  else 
    paste(arg2, "pears")
}

arg1 <- 2
arg2 <- 3

# SOLUTION 1

# similar to what you've tried, but we build the expression first, then eval
# `substitute()` will become your missing argument here

condition <- TRUE
eval(bquote(myFunction(
  .(if(condition) arg1 else substitute()),
  .(if(!condition) arg2 else substitute())
)))
#> [1] "2 apples"

condition <- FALSE
eval(bquote(myFunction(
  .(if(condition) arg1 else substitute()),
  .(if(!condition) arg2 else substitute())
)))
#> [1] "3 pears"

# SOLUTION 2

# feed to the function the right list of arguments depending on condition

condition <- TRUE
do.call(myFunction, list(arg1 = arg1, arg2 = arg2)[xor(condition,c(FALSE, TRUE))])
#> [1] "2 apples"
condition <- FALSE
do.call(myFunction, list(arg1 = arg1, arg2 = arg2)[xor(condition,c(FALSE, TRUE))])
#> [1] "3 pears"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your description is incorrect.  With the code you have, one of `arg1` or `arg2` will be `NULL`.  I suspect the function is testing for missing, not testing for `NULL`.  Neither argument is missing.

What you could do instead is run

```
if (condition) myFunction(arg1 = arg1) else myFunction(arg2 = arg2)
```

Regarding keeping it in a pipeline:  you can certainly wrap this line in a function that's compatible with `magrittr`.

Comment: You're correct, it is testing for missing.  If `arg1 = NULL` then `missing(arg1)` will return false?  I had assumed that `missing(NULL)` would return true.  I'd also assume that there is no way to assign a variable as missing.

This is good to know, thank you.  You're absolutely correct in that the right way to do this is with a conditional call like that.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know there's no way to set a variable to missing other than not to include it.